# Is it possible to do multiple regression on participants' level variables across studies using meta-analysis aggregated data?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am wondering is it possible (or appropriate) to perform multiple regression using participants level variables across studies using meta-analysis data?

I know that usually, meta-regression is performed with study-level variable, explaining how the effect changes across studies due to study-level variables.

But is it possible to produce a correlation table, and collect the variance, and use the correlation to perform a regression analysis?

For example, in 10 studies I got the correlation between A and C, in another 10 studies I got the correlation between B and C. Can I use the summarized effect (the correlation) to perform a regression analysis?

If it is not appropriate, will there any way to do so? Let say if I use IPD meta-analyses, will it be possible?

If you do not have the time to provide me with an answer, you can give me some names on readings that I should look at! I just don't know where to start.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the stats.stackexchange  Please edit your question stating your objectives in detail or in the form of hypotheses.

Comment: Thank you for your welcoming! I think mdewey answered my question. What I wanted to do is some modelling with many different variables. I think 2 stage meta-SEM is the direction I should be looking at!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches used in the literature called one-stage and two-stage.

For the one stage approach you simply perform a multiple regression on the individual participant data as though you had collected it as a multi-centre study with the centres corresponding to the primary studies you are now looking at.

For the two stage approach you perform your regression analysis separately for each study and the extract the statistic of interest from it and meta-analyse those in the usual way. It would seem preferable to use the regression coefficient here.

In your case it seems that you do not have the same moderator variable in each study so the two-stage approach might be easier with an additional study-level moderator corresponding to the different individual-level moderators.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Sorry for my late reply, I was trying to read the information on 2-stage Meta-SEM as you suggested. I agree that this is the best way to accomplish my model! Many thanks!